C++ how to check that the destructor is noexcept?
I need to check that a destructor of a given type is noexcept.
I found std::is_nothrow_destructible_v, but it does not work, as it is true for destructors that do not have noexcept. I see that libstdc++ source is complicated and doing something else, so maybe it's a wrong type trait.
So I am trying to write my own is_noexcept_destructible, but it does not work either. In addition, the same technique with std::declval works for a member function, but not for a destructor. What am I doing wrong?
Here is an example code with questions in comments:
#include <iostream>
#include <type_traits> // is_nothrow_destructible_v

template <typename T>
static constexpr auto is_noexcept_destructible = noexcept(std::declval<T&&>().~T());

class Baddy
{
    int i;
public:
    Baddy();
    ~Baddy(); // may throw!
    void fn(); // may throw!
};

static_assert(is_noexcept_destructible<Baddy>); // why true?
static_assert(std::is_nothrow_destructible_v<Baddy>); // why true?
static_assert(not noexcept(Baddy().~Baddy())); // why universally false?
static_assert(not noexcept(Baddy().fn())); // why universally false?
static_assert(noexcept(std::declval<Baddy&&>().~Baddy())); // why true?
static_assert(not noexcept(std::declval<Baddy&&>().fn())); // OK!

class Gooddy
{
    int i;
public:
    Gooddy() {}
    ~Gooddy() noexcept {}
    void fn() noexcept {}
};

static_assert(is_noexcept_destructible<Gooddy>);
static_assert(std::is_nothrow_destructible_v<Gooddy>);
static_assert(not noexcept(Gooddy().~Gooddy())); // why false?
static_assert(not noexcept(Gooddy().fn())); // why false?
static_assert(noexcept(std::declval<Gooddy&&>().~Gooddy()));
static_assert(noexcept(std::declval<Gooddy&&>().fn())); // OK!

void bad_fn();

Baddy::Baddy(): i{7} {}
Baddy::~Baddy(){ bad_fn(); }
void Baddy::fn() { bad_fn(); }

void bad_fn() { throw std::logic_error{"misbehave"}; }

int main()
{
    auto bad = Baddy{};
    bad.fn(); // crash
    std::cout << "PASSED\n";
}

Live code: https://godbolt.org/z/j3q7nsGrM

Destructors are noexcept by default. No checks are needed. ~Baddy(); // may throw! - no it may not unless noexcept(false) is specified. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32956339/transitioning-to-c11-where-destructors-are-implicitly-declared-with-noexcept

See the Note: "Because the C++ program terminates if a destructor throws an exception during stack unwinding (which usually cannot be predicted), all practical destructors are non-throwing even if they are not declared noexcept." from here

@463035818_is_not_an_ai thank you. I am writing my own allocator (because default is too slow).

@3CxEZiVlQ thank you! once I added noexcept(false) everything fell into places.

see also here https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/destructor in the section on implcitly declared destructors. std::is_nothrow_destructible is already doing what you want. Its just that all destructors you tried so far are no throw. See here for an example that isnt: https://godbolt.org/z/Tex3TWa1G
